# Having difficulty sending small lwip packets immediately using the lwip API

Tags: api, tcp, send, lwip

I am creating a server on a ST Cortex M3 device. I am using the lwip API and FreeRTOS. All is working, but the response time is way off. I am currently using lwip 1.3.2 and FreeRTOS 7.3.

A single client connects to the server and must have some time-critical data sent frequently. These packets are on the order of 6 or so bytes. Other times, I am sending upwards of 20K.

The problem I am having is that these smaller packets seem to be taking forever to be sent. I assume this is because lwip is waiting for more data to be enqueued to make more efficient transmissions. I cannot wait around for 2 or 3 seconds for the data to be sent; the client is expecting the data nominally in a few micro-seconds or milli-seconds.

I have tried using lwip_send and lwip_write. (I understand that one is the same as the other with a flag passed at the end. Just had to try...) I have tried setting TCP_NODELAY on the socket to no avail. I tried to set SO_SNDLOWAT to '1', but this always returned -1, so I do not think it is supported.

I do not want to redo all of my code using TCP RAW. Is there a way to invoke the tcp_output() function outside of TCP RAW mode? Is there any way to speed things up or is this just how slow lwip TCP with small packets is?

Any and all suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

--EDIT--
I would also like to add that once I am ready to transmit, I make sure that my TX task in FreeRTOS is at the highest priority. There are no other tasks running up to the point at which I call lwip_send/write.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly experienced with bare metal lwIP on xilinx and lwip does not wait to send things out.  It will pump packets out as fast as your interrupts are acknowledged based on the ethernet hardware.  I've been using UDP only.  What is coming to mind though, is your problem might be on the receive end.  If you are doing TCP, maybe those small packets are coming out late because you are having receive issues.  What you need to do is find in the code the lowest level point at which ethernet is transmit, put a general purpose output toggle on that.  Then also put a general purpose output toggle on when a ethernet packet is received.  Look at the signals on a scope.  If it confirms your hypothesis, then move the output toggles around to narrow down the issue.  Wash, rinse and repeat until you are down to where the issue its.  It's crude and time consuming, but oftentimes this brute force approach solves many "impossible" embedded software problems, due to pure determination.  Good luck!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a general purpose output toggle"?